# How do you loop through JSON object member variables?

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have a JSON response object like:

> {"1":"absent","2":"sold","3":"sold","4":"sold","5":"sold","6":"sold","7":"sold","8":"sold","9":"sold"}

How can I loop through all of the object's member variables?

The response is variable. It may be like:

> {"5":"absent","23":"sold","24":"sold","26":"sold","29":"sold","41":"sold","42":"sold","42":"sold","42":"sold"}

json query:

```
$.getJSON(myurl + '?action=21' + '&token=' + token + '&id=' + total + '&sell=1', 
   function(data){ 
    for (var i = '0'; i < reply.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i][2];
    alert(obj);
  } 
})
```

Comment: which is actually mentioned on the jQuery API page for getJSON... a little research and you would not have needed us at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript the `for in` loop iterates over the keys of an object.  So you want this:

```
var i;
for (i in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    alert(data[i]);
  }
}
```

The [`hasOwnProperty(i)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is a recommended step when using this style of loop. For simple plain objects like this, it's not totally necessary, buts its also a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/qAWbW/

```
var data = {"1":"absent","2":"sold","3":"sold","4":"sold","5":"sold","6":"sold","7":"sold","8":"sold","9":"sold"};

for (var key in data) {          
    console.log(key + '----' + data[key]);
}​
```

This should work for you

```
$.getJSON(myurl + '?action=21' + '&token=' + token + '&id=' + total +
'&sell=1', 
function(data){ 
   for (var key in data) {          
       console.log(key + '----' + data[key]);
   }  ​
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `for`

```
var data = {
    "1": "absent",
    "2": "sold",
    "3": "sold",
    "4": "sold",
    "5": "sold",
    "6": "sold",
    "7": "sold",
    "8": "sold",
    "9": "sold"
};

for (key in data) {

    console.log(data[key])
}​;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nqHd7/1/)